# Hide/Show NOTES or Files in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

How can I hide/show these buttons in the code, not in the customizer?

[image]

[image]

I know how to enable or disable from aspx but I need to disable and enable at the graph level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no interface for controlling the indicators from a graph.

The alternative is to create a new ASPX page by copying the existing one and removing the indicators.

You can also create a new graph class by inheriting from the existing one:

```
public class APInvoiceEntryNoIndicator : APInvoiceEntry
{
}
```

This new graph can be bound to the new screen. This can be helpful when you want to redirect to the new page, set different access rights etc..